# Editing value is not working Properly in php

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I have created a page where data of the examination and the description displays from database to webpage (page name is manageexam.php)

Code is as follows :
 **manageexam.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin | Manage Exam</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<style>
.active3{
    color:#900;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php include"livetime.php";?>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th class="th" align="left" colspan="2" >
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'])
echo "<span id='welcome'>Congratulation, <span id='company'> ".$_SESSION['username']."</span> you are logged in!</span>";
else
die("You Must be logged in!");
?>
<span class="clock"><span id="clockbox"></span></span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="tdleft"><br>
<span class="message">Admin Controller</span>
<?php include('menu.php');?>
</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFCC" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
<h2>Manage Exams Available:</h2>

<?php 
include('dbconfig.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM examsmeta");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "<strong>Total Exams Available: $numrows </strong>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<table class='table2'>
<tr>
<th width='30%'>Subject Name</th>
<th width='60%'>Description</th>
<th width='30%'>Select</th>
</tr>
<form action= 'manageexam.php' method='post'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row[1]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row[2]. "</td>";
    echo "<td><input name='select' type='checkbox' value=".$row[1]."></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table><br>";

echo "<input class='bttn' type='submit' value='Delete Exam' name='delete'>";
echo " <input class='bttn' type='submit' value='Edit Exam' name='edit' > ";
echo "</form>"
?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td" colspan="2" height="10%">
Status Bar:
<span id="black">
<?php 
if(!isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
{
include('delete.php');

if(isset($_POST['edit'])){

    header('location:editexam.php?id='.$_POST['select']);
    }

}
else
{
echo $_REQUEST['logout'];
    }
?>

</span>
<span class="logout"><a href="logout-handler.php">LOGOUT</a></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Now at this page i have added checkbox in front of each exam and two buttons, One is for Delete exams Permanently and second is for Edit exam. At Editing Exam Whenever i choose any 1 exam (via checkbox) and click on edit Following result displays(shown example of choosing exam commerce) :

```
Unknown column 'Commerce' in 'where clause'
```

Code of **editexam.php** is as follows :

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    if($_REQUEST['id']=='')
    {
        header('location:manageexam.php?message2=Error: Please select a Value!');
    }
    else{
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$query="select * from examsmeta where SubId=".$id;
$res=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin |Edit Exam</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datepickr.css" />
<style>
.active5{
    color:#900;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--text editor.-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
// ===========================================
// INCLUDE THE PLUGIN
// ===========================================
plugins: [
"advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
"searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
"insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"
],
// ===========================================
// PUT PLUGIN'S BUTTON on the toolbar
// ===========================================
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
// ===========================================
// SET RELATIVE_URLS to FALSE (This is required for images to display properly)
// ===========================================
relative_urls: false
});</script>
<!--text editor script close-->

<?php include('livetime.php');?>
<table width="100%" class="table">
<tr>
<th class="th" align="left" colspan="2" >
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'])
echo "<span id='welcome'>Congratulation, <span id='company'> ".$_SESSION['username']."</span> you are logged in!</span>";
else
die("You Must be logged in!");
?>
<span class="clock"><span id="clockbox"></span></span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="tdleft"><br>
<span class="message"> Admin Controller</span>
<?php include('menu.php');?>
</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFCC" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">

<h2>Edit Exams Available </h2>

<form id="regform" action="" method="post">

<div class="wrapper">
<strong>Subject Name: </strong>
<div class="bg">

<input class="input" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
echo $row['name'];
}
?>" name="name"/>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<strong>Description:</strong>
<div class="bg">
<textarea class="textbox"  name="description">
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
echo $row['description']; 
} ?>
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id'];?>" />
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="bttnalign"><a href="editexam.php?id=0"><input class="bttn" type="button" value="Clear">
  <input class="bttn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
</a>
</div>
</form>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td class="td" colspan="2" height="10%">
Status Bar:
<span id="black">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $na=$_POST['name'];
    $nad=$_POST['description'];
    $rid=$_POST['id'];
    $nupdate=mysql_query("UPDATE examsmeta SET Name='".$na."',Description='".$nad."' WHERE SubId='".$rid."'") or die(mysql_error());

header("location:manageexam.php?message2=Data Updated Successfully!");


}
?>
</span>
<span class="logout"><a href="logout-handler.php">LOGOUT</a></span>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--Date Picker-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="datepickr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            new datepickr('datepick', {
                'dateFormat': 'm/d/Y'
            });
        </script>
<!--Date Picker closed-->
</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong, anyone explain please?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $na=$_POST['name'];
    $nad=$_POST['description'];
    $rid=$_POST['id'];
    $nupdate=mysql_query("UPDATE examsmeta SET Name='".$na."',Description='".$nad."' WHERE SubId='".$rid."'") or die(mysql_error());

header("location:manageexam.php?message2=Data Updated Successfully!");


}

Comment: Acc to this error there is column named as 'Commerce' & not present in ur table

Comment: can't even find word 'Commerce' in both of your provided code! this error is related to query, and there no 'Commerce' word at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `$row[1]` as parameter which I assume that is the column with the name.
Change the code below:

```
 echo "<td><input name='select' type='checkbox' value=".$row[1]."></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><input name='select' type='checkbox' value=".$row[0]."></td>";
```

This will pass the id by parameter, (I am assuming that the id column is in the 0 position)/

Comment: It worked , and now i am redirected to the editexam.php page now new error is appearing.

Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\wamp\www\Tomar\php\a\editexam.php on line 84

you can check the editexam.php above in question.

Comment: FInally Everything is Working... THank you very much everyone specially fmodos :)

Comment: Hey fmodos edit function is working properly but after changing that $row[1] to $row[0] delete function is not working. it was working before that change.

Comment: @srp003j i dont see the delete code in your post, but I would assume that the delete where condition is using the name instead of the id